# Paint a path on an image while keeping the image's original size

Tags: android, imageview

In my app I display an image of a document and the user can then sign the document with their finger. This works fine but the problem is that on device with small screens/screen density the size of the signed image will be the size of the imageview its placed it therefor changing the image from its original dimensions making it smaller and unreadable.

There is no issue for devices with large screen sizes because for the most part that dont resize the image.

I load the image by getting the width and height of the imageview and scaling it accordingly to prevent OOM exceptions

```
BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        opt.inMutable = true;
        iv.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreDraw() {
                iv.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                try{
                        int width = iv.getWidth();
                        int height = iv.getHeight();

                        int IMAGE_MAX_SIZE = Math.max(width,height);

                        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                        File i = new File(mDocument.getPath());

                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(i);
                    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis, null, o);
                    fis.close();

                        int scale = 1;
                        if (o.outHeight > IMAGE_MAX_SIZE || o.outWidth > IMAGE_MAX_SIZE) {
                            scale = (int)Math.pow(2, (int) Math.ceil(Math.log(IMAGE_MAX_SIZE /(double) Math.max(o.outHeight, o.outWidth)) / Math.log(0.5)));
                        }

                        //Decode with inSampleSize
                        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
                        o2.inMutable = true;
                        fis = new FileInputStream(i);
                    Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis, null, o2);
                    fis.close();

                        iv.setBitmap(b);
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Then after drawing with their finger I get the image with the path on it by doing

```
Bitmap b = iv.getImage();
```

So my question is, if there a way to take a `Path` and put that on the unscaled image without having to load the unscaled into memory?

Can I create a canvas the size of the original image and just get the path as an image from a canvas then merge the 2 later on my server?

Comment: use `ImageView#getImageMatrix`

Comment: @pskink can you explain a little more? I am not sure what that is going to do (probably due to my lack of knowledge of matrixes)

Comment: when you have your `Path` you have to scale it to match the "big" original image, right? you do that by calling `Path#transform` which takes the transformation `Matrix`

Comment: Ok got that but isn't `getImageMatrix` going to return me the scaled imageviews matrix in this case? I never load the original image into memory and only load the image upon knowing the `inSampleSize` so how do I create a matrix from? Maybe I am way off in my understanding here

Comment: ok so use Matrix#setRectToRect and compute the matrix by yourself (assumming you are using the default scale type)

Comment: and if you are not using default scale type you could still use `getImageMatrix` followed by `postScale` / `preScale` and scale by `inSampleSize` - but i 'm not 100% sure if that would work

Comment: Ah ok that covers part 1 then, but now what about putting that on the original. Right now I just use Canvas#drawPath (canvas holds the scaled bitmap from `new Canvas(bitmap)`) and that draws the path on the scaled image

Comment: if you call Path#transform your path will enlarge to fit the original - of course you can also use Canvas#concat but in this case the stroke width will scale too

Comment: right I got that but calling ImageView#getImage gets me the bitmap with the scaled image and the drawn path all in one. So now if I call `transform` the the path may be in the right place in regards to the original but getImage will show the path off the scaled image wouldn't it? Or would I just set the matrix created from the 2 rect's to the imageview before calling `getImage`?

Comment: you want to draw over the original? so you gotta have the big original `Bitmap` so why the `inSampleSize` downsampling? or you want to draw it on the server side? in other words can you create the big, original `Bitmap` on the phone or it is too big?

Comment: Drawing over the original would be preferred but the inSampleSize is for making sure large images dont cause OutOfMemory errors (Image sizes are unknown come from a third party so I dont want to assume anything). If I have the server handle it my question becomes how do I just get the drawn `Path` as an image so my server can combine the two later?

Comment: so you would send only the drawn bigger path + `PointF` with the offset to translate the drawn big path - you can get the bounds of your path by using `Region` API

Comment: ok so `getImageMatrix` works ok:  https://pastebin.com/raw/dEMZuf9w - you need only to use `postScale`

Comment: and instead of sending any raster `Path` i would send the `Matrix` and the `Path` data and let the server draw it on the original big bitmap - i think many server side langs have path support

Comment: Ah thats what I was just about to ask, so in your example I would keep track of `e.getX()/e.getY()` then send `Matrix inverted` back to the server and the server would take that matrix and translate the pixel path to the image path?

Comment: [this](https://medium.com/square-corner-blog/smooth-signatures-9d92df119ff8) guy uses simple `lineTo` but it could be possible to reduce many straight lines with some `cubicTo` but it would require some upper math...

Comment: btw `inverted.postScale(opts.inSampleSize, opts.inSampleSize);` is wrong - i was too fast - it should be really the ratio of widths and heights, in my case 600f/200f and 400f/133f which is: 3.0 and 3.007518796992481